# Magento upgrade 1.9.1 Google API tab Blank

Tags: magento, configuration, system, upgrade

I have upgraded magento 1.7.2 to 1.9.1, everything seems to work fine except Google API tab under system > configuration is loading blank page.

Is this something common? can anyone help with this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming. You should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Answer (score 0):

This issue occur many time while you upgrade your Magento version. Which way you have upgrade your magento ? some times there where missing some file so it display blank page so please check your all file is it proper or not. Make you sure that your cache is must be flush.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Upgrade was performed by overwriting 1.7 files with 1.9 files, all cache and sessions were cleared and all reindexed, however that didnt fix the issue.